# AngularJS directive set different value for each item in ng-repeat only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am ng-repeating a directive and need to set a background color selected randomly from a array of colors on each instance.

I've tried this but it has a new color set every time the link function is run

```
link: ( scope, element, attrs ) ->

  colors = ["#ED6533", "#33EDC4", "#ED325D", "#33BCF2", "#EDC434", "#ED33BC"]
  scope.bgcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

How can the value be set only once on each directive instance?

Comment: Link should only run once after element is added, how do you build your ng-repeat? It might be the case that your ng-repeat rebuilds the entire list when it should not. Plunker would be nice. Also, do you want random background color for all the elements (as every element different color) or one common bgcolor for all?

Comment: can you explain what you mean _How can value be set only once on each directive instance_?

Comment: So each ng-repeated element should have a different color, but it should they should be set when the page loads and remain the same after that. You're right @BroiSatse link should only be called once. This is a list of directives for user profiles. Seems Ng-repeat is rebuilding the list every time the application checks the online status of users.

Comment: @item, can you provide working sample? on plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: @item - can you show your ng-repeat in the template?

Comment: i'm pretty sure you just need use `track by` but working sample can help understand

Comment: Yep, track by prevents the current directives from being redrawn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to add `scope: {}` to your directive, where you placed the link function:

```
...
scope: {},
link: ( scope, element, attrs )...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `::` binding:

```
<directive:color style="background-color: {{::bgcolor}}" class="block" ng-repeat="i in items">asdf</directive:color>
```

Look at [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/batIGD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Track by seems to be the solution. Problem was that the list was being refreshed and redrawing all elements.

> Behind the scenes ngRepeat adds a $$hashKey property to each task to keep track of it. If you replace the original tasks with new tasks objects from the server, even if those are in fact totally identical to your original tasks, they won’t have the $$hashKey property and so ngRepeat won’t know they represent the same elements.
>   In Angular 1.2 a new addition was made to the syntax of ngRepeat: the amazingly awesome track by clause. It allows you to specify your own key for ngRepeat to identify objects by, instead of just generating unique IDs. This means that you can change the above to be ng-repeat="task in tasks track by task.id" and since the ID would be the same in both your original tasks and the updated ones from the server – ngRepeat will know not to recreate the DOM elements and reuse them. http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/